# retrieve & populate .jsp page from MySql

Tags: java, mysql

How may i retrieve & populate output components at a .jsp page with MySQL? Also, how may i retrieve records pertaining to a particular item_id? Im using IBM Rational Application Developer.

The following is what i have so far, ridden with errors or missing statements I'm sure.

@DB.class

```
public Items getItemDetails() {
                     Connection con = connect(true);
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String select = "SELECT * FROM TEST.ITEMBOUGHT WHERE ITEM_ID = ?";
            Items item = null;

            try {
                stmt = con.prepareStatement(select);
                //stmt.setString(1,item_id);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //System.out.println("Record Found!");
                    item = new Items();
                    //item.setItem_id(item_id);
                    item.setItem_name(rs.getString("item_name"));
                    item.setItem_bidding_start_price(rs.getDouble("item_bidding_starting_price"));
                    item.setItem_bidding_highest_price(rs.getDouble("item_bidding_highest_price"));
                    item.setItem_description(rs.getString("item_description"));
                    item.setItem_quantity(rs.getInt("item_quantity"));
                    item.setItem_closing_date(rs.getDate("item_closing_date"));
                    item.setItem_image(rs.getString("item_image"));
                    item.setItem_status(rs.getString("item_closing_date"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                item = null;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (rs   != null) rs.close();
                    if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
                    if (con  != null) con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
            return item;
        }
```

Comment: That's fine but what exactly is your problem with the code you have posted?

Comment: @Lion: I am unable to display them at the output components. In the 1st place, I do not even know if the sql statement is correct & return any results.

Comment: Please note that you have to be more precise about your question. Otherwise, it's not that someone is going to copy your code and test accordingly and it's indeed hard to test because doing so requires to have relevant tables in the database which is not possible to be created at a glance and without knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Alrite, I'll do so, thank you anw.

Comment: *"I do not even know if the sql statement .. return any results."*  You would if the statement `//System.out.println("Record Found!");` was not commented out and you examined the logs!  Alternately use an IDE set-up for web/DB development and step through it using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you Andrew :) Btw here's the scenario, i wish to do an auction site where users view the items available. Therefore i need to display the items @ a .jsp page for a start, with MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PreparedStatement for the SQL: `SELECT * FROM TEST.ITEMBOUGHT WHERE ITEM_ID = ?`.  That means you must tell JDBC what value to replace the question mark (?) in query string, but you put comment on it in `//stmt.setString(1,item_id);`

If you want to select ITEM_ID 1 and ITEM_ID is INTEGER (numeric field), you can use the following code:

```
public Items getItemDetails() {
   Connection con = connect(true);
   PreparedStatement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   String select = "SELECT * FROM TEST.ITEMBOUGHT WHERE ITEM_ID = ?";
   Items item = null;

   try {
       stmt = con.prepareStatement(select);
       stmt.setInt(1,1);
       rs = stmt.executeQuery();
       while (rs.next()) {
          ... // and so on
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

If you want to select all records, remove the WHERE clause: `SELECT * FROM TEST.ITEMBOUGHT`. If you don't need PreparedStatement, you can rewrite the code into:

```
Statement stmt = null;
...
try {
...
   stmt = con.createStatement() ;
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(select) ;
...
}
```

Comment: Assuming that i wish to populate the output components with the WHERE clause, ie. item_id of 1, how may i edit the above code then? Im confused, sorry. Any tutorials you may point me also?

Comment: If item_id is INTEGER, you can use `stmt.setInt(1,1);`.  But if item_id is VARCHAR, you can use `stmt.setString(1,"1");`.  You can read more in [Oracle JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)